# Filter Map<String,List<Object>> Using Java Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

```java
class Custom{
   String itemId,
   long createdTS
   //constructor
   public Custom(String itemId,long createdTS)
}
```

I have two maps which are

```
Map<String,Long> itemIDToFilterAfterTS;
Map<String,List<Custom>> itemIDToCustoms;
```

I want to filter 2nd map itemIDToCustoms values using 1st map itemIDToTimestampMap value for item using java streams.
eg.

```java
itemIDToFilterAfterTS = new HashMap();
itemIDToFilterAfterTS.put("1",100);
itemIDToFilterAfterTS.put("2",200);
itemIDToFilterAfterTS.put("3",300);

itemIDToCustoms = new HashMap();
List<Custom> listToFilter = new ArrayList();
listToFilter.add(new Custom("1",50));
listToFilter.add(new Custom("1",90));
listToFilter.add(new Custom("1",120));
listToFilter.add(new Custom("1",130));
itemIDToCustoms.put("1",listToFilter)
```

Now I want to use java streams and want the filtered result map for which getKey("1") gives filtered list of Custom object which has createdTS > 100 (100 will be fetched from itemIDToFilterAfterTS.getKey("1"))

```
Map<String,List<Custom>> filteredResult will be 
Map{
   "1" : List of (Custom("1",120),Custom("1",130))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream syntax here is a bit too much

```java
itemIDToCustoms = itemIDToCustoms.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
            e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(val -> val.createdTS > itemIDToFilterAfterTS.get(e.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

More readable with a for loop + stream

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Custom>> e : itemIDToCustoms.entrySet()) {
    long limit = itemIDToFilterAfterTS.get(e.getKey());
    List<Custom> newValue = e.getValue().stream().filter(val -> val.createdTS > limit).collect(Collectors.toList());
    itemIDToCustoms.put(e.getKey(), newValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated..It worked for me!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map#computeIfPresent` method like this:

which allows you to compute value of a mapping for specified key if key is already associated with a value

```
public Object computeIfPresent(Object key,BiFunction remappingFunction)
```

So you can perform it like:

```
itemIDToFilterAfterTS.forEach((key, value) ->
            itemIDToCustoms.computeIfPresent(key, (s, customs) -> customs.stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getCreatedTS() > value)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```